# How to do compile make make install as permanent install so that it does not give this error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, packages, gstreamer

I was building from source to test one bug i was facing, and I did `apt-get remove gstreamer` once.  Since then when I do `gst-launch` it throws following:

```
$ gst-launch --version
/usr/local/bin/gst-launch-0.10: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But if I do `/home/user/Downloads/gstreamer/tools/gst-launch --version` it shows latest version. Do you know how can I now solve it?

Comment: It looks like you need to do sudo make install from you Downloads/gstreamer folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the folder you built from source in, and then use

`sudo make install`

You will probably need your password at this point.